# Incorrect applying of the LUT on the background in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, lookup-tables

I have used this tutorial https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-post-processing-3dlut.html of ThreeJS

I want to apply LUT on a video, but as an experiment, tried to work with an image.
And I've got a problem that after applying the LUT my result doesn't fit with a result from Photoshop.

Look at the images below:

1. Original
2. Lut applied by ThreeJS
3. Lut applied by Photoshop

[image: Original]

[image: ThreeJS]

[image: Photoshop]

JS fiddle where you can reproduce the problem (code almost the same like source)
https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene_Ilyin/2e56mzaw/13/
Link to PNG LUT can be found in code or use direct link https://i.ibb.co/CJ27jKF/bthree-s8.png

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
// Three.js - postprocessing - 3DLUT w/loader
// from https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/threejs-postprocessing-3dlut-w-loader.html

import * as lutParser from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/lut-reader.js';
import * as dragAndDrop from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/drag-and-drop.js';
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r119/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r119/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r119/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import {EffectComposer} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r119/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js';
import {RenderPass} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r119/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js';
import {ShaderPass} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r119/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js';
import {GUI} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/../3rdparty/dat.gui.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();

  const lutTextures = [
    { name: 'identity',           size: 2, filter: true , },
    { name: 'identity no filter', size: 2, filter: false, },
    { name: 'MY LUT', size: 8, filter: true, url: 'https://i.ibb.co/CJ27jKF/bthree-s8.png' }
  ];

  const makeIdentityLutTexture = function() {
    const identityLUT = new Uint8Array([
        0,   0,   0, 255,  // black
      255,   0,   0, 255,  // red
        0,   0, 255, 255,  // blue
      255,   0, 255, 255,  // magenta
        0, 255,   0, 255,  // green
      255, 255,   0, 255,  // yellow
        0, 255, 255, 255,  // cyan
      255, 255, 255, 255,  // white
    ]);

    return function(filter) {
      const texture = new THREE.DataTexture(identityLUT, 4, 2, THREE.RGBAFormat);
      texture.minFilter = filter;
      texture.magFilter = filter;
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
      texture.flipY = false;
      return texture;
    };
  }();

  const makeLUTTexture = function() {
    const imgLoader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
    const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');

    return function(info) {
      const texture = makeIdentityLutTexture(
          info.filter ? THREE.LinearFilter : THREE.NearestFilter);

      if (info.url) {
        const lutSize = info.size;

        // set the size to 2 (the identity size). We'll restore it when the
        // image has loaded. This way the code using the lut doesn't have to
        // care if the image has loaded or not
        info.size = 2;

        imgLoader.load(info.url, function(image) {
          const width = lutSize * lutSize;
          const height = lutSize;
          info.size = lutSize;
          ctx.canvas.width = width;
          ctx.canvas.height = height;
          ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
          const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

          texture.image.data = new Uint8Array(imageData.data.buffer);
          texture.image.width = width;
          texture.image.height = height;
          texture.needsUpdate = true;
        });
      }

      return texture;
    };
  }();

  lutTextures.forEach((info) => {
    // if not size set get it from the filename
    if (!info.size) {
      // assumes filename ends in '-s<num>[n]'
      // where <num> is the size of the 3DLUT cube
      // and [n] means 'no filtering' or 'nearest'
      //
      // examples:
      //    'foo-s16.png' = size:16, filter: true
      //    'bar-s8n.png' = size:8, filter: false
      const m = /-s(\d+)(n*)\.[^.]+$/.exec(info.url);
      if (m) {
        info.size = parseInt(m[1]);
        info.filter = info.filter === undefined ? m[2] !== 'n' : info.filter;
      }
    }

    info.texture = makeLUTTexture(info);
  });

  let lutNameIndexMap = {};
  function makeLutNameIndexMap() {
    lutNameIndexMap = {};
    lutTextures.forEach((info, ndx) => {
      lutNameIndexMap[info.name] = ndx;
    });
  }
  makeLutNameIndexMap();  // called so we can set lutSettings below

  const lutSettings = {
    dummy: () => {},
    lut: lutNameIndexMap.identity,
  };
  const gui = new GUI({ width: 300 });
  gui.addFolder('Choose LUT or Drag&Drop LUT File(s)');

  let lutGUI;
  function updateGUI() {
    makeLutNameIndexMap();
    if (lutGUI) {
      gui.remove(lutGUI);
    }
    lutGUI = gui.add(lutSettings, 'lut', lutNameIndexMap);
  }
  updateGUI();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const sceneBG = new THREE.Scene();
  const cameraBG = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1);

  let bgMesh;
  let bgTexture;
  {
    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    bgTexture = loader.load('https://i.ibb.co/XDTN30r/source.png');
    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2, 2);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: bgTexture,
      depthTest: false,
    });
    bgMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    sceneBG.add(bgMesh);
  }

  function frameArea(sizeToFitOnScreen, boxSize, boxCenter, camera) {
    const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = sizeToFitOnScreen * 0.5;
    const halfFovY = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov * .5);
    const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);
    // compute a unit vector that points in the direction the camera is now
    // in the xz plane from the center of the box
    const direction = (new THREE.Vector3())
        .subVectors(camera.position, boxCenter)
        .multiply(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1))
        .normalize();

    // move the camera to a position distance units way from the center
    // in whatever direction the camera was from the center already
    camera.position.copy(direction.multiplyScalar(distance).add(boxCenter));

    // pick some near and far values for the frustum that
    // will contain the box.
    camera.near = boxSize / 100;
    camera.far = boxSize * 100;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // point the camera to look at the center of the box
    camera.lookAt(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, boxCenter.z);
  }

  {
    /* const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
    gltfLoader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/models/3dbustchallange_submission/scene.gltf', (gltf) => {
      const root = gltf.scene;
      scene.add(root);
    
      // fix materials from r114
      root.traverse(({material}) => {
        if (material) {
          material.depthWrite = true;
        }
      });
    
      root.updateMatrixWorld();
      // compute the box that contains all the stuff
      // from root and below
      const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);
    
      const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
      const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
      frameArea(boxSize * 0.4, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);
    
      // update the Trackball controls to handle the new size
      controls.maxDistance = boxSize * 10;
      controls.target.copy(boxCenter);
      controls.update();
    }); */
  }

  const lutShader = {
    uniforms: {
      tDiffuse: { value: null },
      lutMap:  { value: null },
      lutMapSize: { value: 1, },
    },
    vertexShader: `
      varying vec2 vUv;
      void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      }
    `,
    fragmentShader: `
      #include <common>

      #define FILTER_LUT true

      uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
      uniform sampler2D lutMap;
      uniform float lutMapSize;

      varying vec2 vUv;

      vec4 sampleAs3DTexture(sampler2D tex, vec3 texCoord, float size) {
        float sliceSize = 1.0 / size;                  // space of 1 slice
        float slicePixelSize = sliceSize / size;       // space of 1 pixel
        float width = size - 1.0;
        float sliceInnerSize = slicePixelSize * width; // space of size pixels
        float zSlice0 = floor( texCoord.z * width);
        float zSlice1 = min( zSlice0 + 1.0, width);
        float xOffset = slicePixelSize * 0.5 + texCoord.x * sliceInnerSize;
        float yRange = (texCoord.y * width + 0.5) / size;
        float s0 = xOffset + (zSlice0 * sliceSize);

        #ifdef FILTER_LUT

          float s1 = xOffset + (zSlice1 * sliceSize);
          vec4 slice0Color = texture2D(tex, vec2(s0, yRange));
          vec4 slice1Color = texture2D(tex, vec2(s1, yRange));
          float zOffset = mod(texCoord.z * width, 1.0);
          return mix(slice0Color, slice1Color, zOffset);

        #else

          return texture2D(tex, vec2( s0, yRange));

        #endif
      }

      void main() {
        vec4 originalColor = texture2D(tDiffuse, vUv);
        gl_FragColor = sampleAs3DTexture(lutMap, originalColor.xyz, lutMapSize);
      }
    `,
  };

  const lutNearestShader = {
    uniforms: {...lutShader.uniforms},
    vertexShader: lutShader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: lutShader.fragmentShader.replace('#define FILTER_LUT', '//'),
  };

  const effectLUT = new ShaderPass(lutShader);
  effectLUT.renderToScreen = true;
  const effectLUTNearest = new ShaderPass(lutNearestShader);
  effectLUTNearest.renderToScreen = true;

  const renderModel = new RenderPass(scene, camera);
  renderModel.clear = false;  // so we don't clear out the background
  const renderBG = new RenderPass(sceneBG, cameraBG);

  const rtParameters = {
    minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    format: THREE.RGBFormat,
  };
  const composer = new EffectComposer(renderer, new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(1, 1, rtParameters));

  composer.addPass(renderBG);
  //composer.addPass(renderModel);
  composer.addPass(effectLUT);
  //composer.addPass(effectLUTNearest);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth * window.devicePixelRatio | 0;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight * window.devicePixelRatio | 0;

    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  let then = 0;
  function render(now) {
    now *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
    const delta = now - then;
    then = now;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      const canvasAspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.aspect = canvasAspect;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      composer.setSize(canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // scale the background plane to keep the image's
      // aspect correct.
      // Note the image may not have loaded yet.
      const imageAspect = bgTexture.image ? bgTexture.image.width / bgTexture.image.height : 1;
      const aspect = imageAspect / canvasAspect;
      bgMesh.scale.x = aspect > 1 ? aspect : 1;
      bgMesh.scale.y = aspect > 1 ? 1 : 1 / aspect;
    }

    const lutInfo = lutTextures[ lutSettings.lut ];

    const effect = lutInfo.filter ? effectLUT : effectLUTNearest;
    effectLUT.enabled = lutInfo.filter;
    effectLUTNearest.enabled = !lutInfo.filter;

    const lutTexture = lutInfo.texture;
    effect.uniforms.lutMap.value = lutTexture;
    effect.uniforms.lutMapSize.value = lutInfo.size;

    composer.render(delta);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  dragAndDrop.setup({msg: 'Drop LUT File here'});
  dragAndDrop.onDropFile(readLUTFile);

  function readLUTFile(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const lut = lutParser.lutTo2D3Drgb8(lutParser.parse(e.target.result));
      const {size, data, name} = lut;
      const texture = new THREE.DataTexture(data, size * size, size, THREE.RGBFormat);
      texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
      texture.flipY = false;
      const lutTexture = {
        name: (name && name.toLowerCase().trim() !== 'untitled')
          ? name
          : file.name,
        size: size,
        filter: true,
        texture,
      };
      lutTextures.push(lutTexture);
      lutSettings.lut = lutTextures.length - 1;
      updateGUI();

    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
}

main();
</script>
```

My question is how can I use ThreeJS to get valid result? Any other options how to solve my problem (please remember that I want to apply LUT on video) are welcome.

Comment: How did you create the LUT? Try creating an identity LUT png [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/threejs-postprocessing-adobe-lut-to-png-converter.html) meaning just right click on the image and save the PNG. Don't drag a LUT. Load that PNG into photoshop, apply the photoshop LUT, save the PNG. Use that PNG as your LUT. Also post the actual photoshop LUT somewhere.

Comment: Your algorithm of actions is works for me. I've got the same result as in photoshop. That looks very inspiring! I will do additional tests with other filters.

Before, I did drag&drop a CUBE file into the converter in the end of this tutorial https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-post-processing-3dlut.html
I've checked the text in tutorial again and it looks logical for me. Is something wrong with tutorial or I do not understand something?

Comment: The importer for LUTs probably has bugs. Would need a copy of your LUT from Photoshop to check it.

Comment: yes, the lut importer had bugs. Those bugs are fixed now and the luts files should import correctly.

Comment: Big thanks for your help @gman, now all works fine.